# Cannot debug method in Class in Angular Lazy-Loaded Module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-modules

Recently, I try to debug the methods in my class. I tried several way: using Webstorm Debugging, Augury, Browser Debugging Tool but the results are the same.

I started by put a breakpoint at the begin of the method.
Then I refresh the browser and the browser catch the event of the method, however   the application just begin loading its resources. I haven't click or fire the event.
But when I Click to activate/ fire the event, nothing happen. 
Anybody suggest?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?